# Check support for RFC 6895 on linux Debian system

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dns, debian-stretch

I would like to check if a Debian Stretch system supports [RFC 6895, Domain Name System (DNS) IANA Considerations (BCP 42)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6895). It is acting as a DNS client only, and it is not a DNS server.

Is there any command or tool that can help me?
Any documentation that I can use to check it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "support"? The whole document is about IANA operations, not about software in the first place, so "client or server" doesn't even enter the picture.

Comment: Thank you @user1686. If I understand well, the RFC includes implementation details, that are best practices, not mandatory. I would like to know if the implementation of the DNS client supports or uses these non-mandatory practices.

Comment: Could you clarify which specific parts of the RFC you mean? Most I can find is "Some implementations do X" and "There have been implementations which do X", but nothing really that would say "implementations must/should/ought/may do X".

Comment: @user1686, thank you. I see your point. I was looking for compatibility with all the content of the RFC, but maybe it is not the correct approach. I was expecting to: (1) find a tool that tells if the implementation is compatible with the RFC; or (2) to find some comments in the source code of the implementation of the DNS client in Linux stating that the code implements the requirements of the RFC.

Comment: That's exactly the point I'm trying to make: the RFC doesn't state any requirements for code to begin with. The practices it talks about are purely administrative policy -- as in, how the _person_ performing the IANA role should manage the registries on request from RFC authors.